# Implementing a selectable requirements with level of advancement in a web app

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, concepts, implementations

I'm doing a project to teach myself more about MongoDB and ASP.NET development and I am stuck. The project is a mockup of a JobBoard website, where Companies would post offers for potential Employees.

I'm stuck near the part where I want to implement the requirements for the job. I found a very cool looking system on one website.
(I don't know if providing the specific link is against the rules, so I will provide an image)[image: 1]

However I have no idea how to implement it on the backend side. My best idea would be a something like

```json
tech: {
  Agile: 2,
  Python: 2
}
```

in the offer and so on, but I have no idea how to implement something like this as a selectable options for the person who posts the offer.

My best idea would be some kind of an array with all possible options and only one selectable. but that sounds to me like a terrible way to handle this problem. Are there smarter or simply better to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1):

The tech world is constantly and rapidly changing. This means that whatever technologies you decide to list on your job board, tomorrow there will be a recruiter who wants to list a technology you haven't heard of or didn't consider to include.

To avoid that problem, give the recruiters a simple text field (possibly with auto-completion) to enter the technology and a drop-down list to select the corresponding desired proficiency level.

The corresponding representation in JSON would then be:

```
tech: [
  {
    name: "Agile",
    proficiency: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Python",
    proficiency: 5
  }
]
```